# What Sound Doth Thy Soul Fetch?

Tags: word-sequence

Here is a sequence of seven words which follows a certain pattern:

```
DONUT, REGIME, MIASMA, FATHER, SOLDIER, LAUD, TIARA
```

Please give a word that would fit as the next term in the sequence, and an explanation for why your word continues the pattern.

Comment: By the way, "thine soul" does not make sense, as the word "soul" begins with a consonant and not a vowel, wherefore it should be "thy soul". Was this intended?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that distinction - thanks. Nothing would change if the title said "thy" instead.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the title to make that change (and to add a hint).

Comment: Well, like you said, it doesn't make much of a difference anyway in terms of meaning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, piggybacking off of @Duck,

> **Dope** would work. However, things like **dog** and **dowel** would not, since the first syllable must sound like "**Doh**"

Comment: That works! Yes, Duck had most of the answer. The words in the sequence start with the solfege "words", but moreover, they start with the same sound as well. Try coming up with your own complete set - it was pretty tricky for me!

Comment: How did I not see that one?!

Answer (score 5):

> Take the first two letters of each word and then you will find the musical scale. The next one is do so it could be anything with the first two letters of DO like DOnuts. Do re mi fa so la ti do

Comment: This is about 80% of the intended solution. I would argue that two of your suggestions do not work. Also, perhaps you want to add a spoiler to your answer.

Comment: @jamisans Is there another pattern I am missing to find exactly one word? And what spoiler?

Comment: There is another part to the pattern. More than one word can work. I meant a spoiler tag so that your answer can be hidden from those who want to try to solve the puzzle on their own: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers

Comment: @jamisans Is it that all of the words have more than one vowel?

Comment: That's not it. Think more about the sequence you've already identified and the way in which it's used.

Comment: Is it that the last two letters have a vowel and a consonant?

Comment: That's not it. It might help to read the words aloud.

Comment: I think @Duck's reasoning is sound, but it could be even more sound.